# API gets data but shows "index out of range" error when I try to extract a piece of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, api

I am new to python and I haven't found a similar problem on this platform that's why I decided to ask.

Help me point out the error.

This is the API Data from Tequila. I am working with several cities but only extracted two for illustration.

```json
[{'id': 'cape-town_za', 'active': True, 'name': 'Cape Town', 'slug': 'cape-town-south-africa', 'slug_en': 'cape-town-south-africa', 'code': 'CPT', 'alternative_names': [], 'rank': 125, 'global_rank_dst': 39, 'dst_popularity_score': 1543371.0, 'timezone': 'Africa/Johannesburg', 'population': 3433441, 'airports': 1, 'stations': 0, 'hotels': 0, 'bus_stations': 0, 'subdivision': None, 'autonomous_territory': None, 'country': {'id': 'ZA', 'name': 'South Africa', 'slug': 'south-africa', 'code': 'ZA'}, 'region': {'id': 'southern-africa', 'name': 'Southern Africa', 'slug': 'southern-africa'}, 'continent': {'id': 'africa', 'name': 'Africa', 'slug': 'africa', 'code': 'AF'}, 'nearby_country': None, 'location': {'lat': -33.924869, 'lon': 18.424055}, 'tags': [{'tag': 'activities', 'month_to': -1, 'month_from': -1}, {'tag': 'beach', 'month_to': -1, 'month_from': -1}], 'alternative_departure_points': [{'id': 'CPT', 'distance': 18.55, 'duration': 1101.2}], 'providers': [1175, 1282], 'car_rentals': [{'provider_id': 1175, 'providers_locations': ['19065', '657388']}], 'type': 'city'}]
[{'city': 'Dubai ', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 290, 'id': 2}, {'city': 'Namibia ', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 42, 'id': 3}, {'city': 'Tokyo', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 485, 'id': 4}, {'city': 'Sydney', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 551, 'id': 5}, {'city': 'Istanbul', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 95, 'id': 6}, {'city': 'Kuala Lumpur', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 414, 'id': 7}, {'city': 'New York', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 240, 'id': 8}, {'city': 'San Francisco', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 260, 'id': 9}, {'city': 'Cape Town', 'iataCode': None, 'lowestPrice': 378, 'id': 10}]
```

This is my code. I want to extract the "code" from the API data above.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

TEQUILA_API_KEY = MY_API KEY
TEQUILA_ENDPOINT = "https://api.tequila.kiwi.com"

class FlightSearch:
    
    def get_destination_code(self, city_name):
        location_endpoint = f"{TEQUILA_ENDPOINT}/locations/query"
        headers = {"apikey": TEQUILA_API_KEY}
        query = {"term": city_name, "location_types": "city"}
        response = requests.get(url=location_endpoint, headers=headers, params=query)
        results = response.json()["locations"]
        code = results[0]["code"]
        pprint(results)
```

Whenever I run the code, I get the code for the city in index 0, which is "CPT," followed by the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\helly\PycharmProjects\day44\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    row["iataCode"] = flight_search.get_destination_code(row["city"])
  File "C:\Users\Helly\PycharmProjects\day44\flight_search.py", line 23, in get_destination_code
    code = results[0]["code"]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Where is the error in this code?

Comment: It means `response.json()["locations"]` is an empty list.

Comment: It's not empty, I've even printed it out, which is the data above.

Comment: Then `results[0]` should *not* be raising that error…

Comment: How should I rewrite the code then, since I'm stuck here?

Comment: @Wiz98234 try to print out the result of the API call: `print(response.json())` then check how it looks.

Comment: You say you're getting that output but also that you're getting the error when clearly the error comes before any output from your code.  Is the output from putting in something like "data = response.json()" then print(data)?  Can you post the code that includes the bit where you print what you're seeing?

Comment: Let's put it this way: you're *searching* for some data, probably based on user input. It's entirely possible the search term does not yield any results. You need to be prepared for the API to return an empty list in this case. Your error is assuming that there will always be *something* in the list.